# How to do calculations in grid view based on date

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server-2008

how to do emi calculation

for ex i have taken loan 50000

for 50000 i have to pay emi monthly 5000 for 10 months

start date is 1st Mar 2015
end date is 1st Dec 2015.

and i have inserted all these values in database those are 
Name
TotalAmount
StartDate
EndDate 
MonthlyPay

and i have binded these values to grid view also

my problem is , i want to show extra column in grid that is due amount ,when start date is crossed 1 month,show due amount is 5000 , and it crossed 
2 months show 10000 and this so on for 10 months and then stop.

can you please suggest me how to do this, or give me any example for emi payment page,
if you want code i will attach

Comment: can you share your gridview code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should not be too difficult.
Step 1. Prepare a Numbers table in your database with one column N as int. Populate it with values 1 to 180 (for a 15 year loan period) If you think the loan period can be higher, populate more data accordingly.
Step 2. Join your table (you have not told what your table name is, so let us assume it is EMI) to the Numbers table like this:

```
SELECT 
    * 
FROM 
    EMI 
    INNER JOIN Numbers on DATEDIFF(m,EMI.StartDate,EMI.EndDate) >= Numbers.N
```

This will explode your EMI tables by the no of months between start date and end date.
Step 3. Now you need to calculate the due amount which is (MonthlyPay * no of months passed). You will also have to calculate a due date by adding to the start date.

```
SELECT 
    EMI.*
    ,DATEADD(m,N,StartDate) AS DueDate
    ,(Numbers.N * MonthlyPay) AS DueAmount
FROM 
    EMI 
    INNER JOIN Numbers on DATEDIFF(m,EMI.StartDate,EMI.EndDate) >= Numbers.N
ORDER BY
    EMI.Name
    ,Numbers.N
```

Let me know if this solves your problem

Comment: Thank you so much sir..how can i bind this to grid view sir, i want to show like , a member with start date ,end date , monthly pay, total months,and due amount, and when i update member payment due amount should show zero...

Comment: @madhugoud What is the schema of the table where you are storing member payment?
You can make a sql view from this query and bind your gridview to the sql view.

Comment: if date difference is 12 months it is showing 12 rows sir. i want to show like  for example, start date is 1st jan 2015 and end date is 1st dec 2015 monthly pay is 2000. then it show monthly pay 20000 should consider actual date and display

Comment: @madhugoud can you post an image of what my query is returning? and then let me know what change you are looking for.

Comment: @madhugoud The data looks good to me. What change do you want?

Comment: target of my page is... updating payment details .. i want show due amount till today's date , if i have not paid money for last two months , show last 2 months total as due amount, and if i update show due amount is zero, whenever the date is changed again show due amount (i.e monthly pay )

Comment: am storing all details like Name startdate enddate Total amount noofmonths monthly pay  in PaymentTracker1 table using [SP_PaymentTracker]

Comment: oh, so you are not storing actual payments in this table. You are assuming that all past payments have been made and you want to show the due amount based on the date when this query is returned. Am I right?

Comment: yes sir, i have binded all those details to gridview sir, in that only i want to show due amount sir , and i want to update payment details on edit

Comment: Change:  (Numbers.N * MonthlyPay) AS DueAmount to 
        CASE WHEN GETDATE() > StartDate THEN (Numbers.N - DATEDIFF(m,StartDate,GETDATE())) * MonthlyPay ELSE Numbers.N * MonthlyPay AS DueAmount

Comment: Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'AS'.                 SELECT 
    PaymentTracker1.*
    ,DATEADD(m,N,StartDate) AS DueDate
    ,CASE WHEN GETDATE() > StartDate THEN (Numbers.N - DATEDIFF(m,StartDate,GETDATE())) * MonthlyPay ELSE (Numbers.N * MonthlyPay) AS DueAmount
FROM 
    PaymentTracker1 
    INNER JOIN Numbers on DATEDIFF(m,PaymentTracker1.StartDate,PaymentTracker1.EndDate) >= Numbers.N
ORDER BY
    PaymentTracker1.Name
    ,Numbers.N

Comment: my mistake - did not use END to complete the case statement.
Change: (Numbers.N * MonthlyPay) AS DueAmount to CASE WHEN GETDATE() > StartDate THEN (Numbers.N - DATEDIFF(m,StartDate,GETDATE())) * MonthlyPay ELSE Numbers.N * MonthlyPay END AS DueAmount

Comment: Thanks for your help sir.. and can you please suggest me how to do payment operation in grid , i.e showing due amount and updating payments

Comment: what do you mean by updating payments?

Comment: yes sir , can you suggest me how to do that. i have binded that resulted value to grid , all values are binding (one member with 24 months ) , am trying to bind in one row with showing total due

Comment: Madhu, I can help you with SQL, but unfortunately, my skills with application/coding are not good enough...

Comment: ok sir thank you so much for your help. i can do further code

Comment: http://i.stack.imgur.com/crl7M.png                  hi sir ... can you please find the out put  image of query , how to show only particular this month record ... after month crossed i wants to show next month record

Comment: Hi sir ..by using that query all records are retrieving, how to retrieve only current month

Comment: SELECT 
    PaymentTracker1.*
    , convert(varchar(20),DATEADD(m,N,StartDate),110) AS DueDate
    ,(Numbers.N * MonthlyPay) AS DueAmount
FROM 
    PaymentTracker1 
    INNER JOIN Numbers on DATEDIFF(m,PaymentTracker1.StartDate,PaymentTracker1.EndDate) >= Numbers.N 
    
    where  datepart(mm,DATEADD(mm,N,StartDate))= datepart(mm,getdate()) and  datepart(yy,DATEADD(y,N,StartDate))= datepart(yy,getdate())
ORDER BY
    PaymentTracker1.Name
    ,Numbers.N...... by using above where condition am getting only this month values but also same month 2016 and 17 values also showing how to fix it sir

Comment: Hi Madhu, sorry I wasn't available yesterday. Is this still an issue?

Comment: i have used  where condition to retrive current date and am getting current moonth values as well as next year values also find the out put image                              http://i.stack.imgur.com/LMg1m.png

Comment: this is query sir   SELECT 
    PaymentTracker1.*
    , convert(varchar(20),DATEADD(m,N,StartDate),110) AS DueDate
    ,(Numbers.N * MonthlyPay) AS DueAmount
FROM 
    PaymentTracker1 
    INNER JOIN Numbers on DATEDIFF(m,PaymentTracker1.StartDate,PaymentTracker1.EndDate) >= Numbers.N 
    
    where  datepart(mm,DATEADD(mm,N,StartDate))= datepart(mm,getdate()) and  datepart(yy,DATEADD(y,N,StartDate))= datepart(yy,getdate())
ORDER BY
    PaymentTracker1.Name
    ,Numbers.N